# APNS wrapper for ColdFusion?

Tags: iphone, coldfusion, apple-push-notifications

Is there any APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) wrapper for ColdFusion?

Or does this Java one work?

Java: http://code.google.com/p/javapns/

PHP: http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/

If not existed, shall we start a open source project on riaforge / github / google code? port from PHP's?

Comment: Not an expert in this area but does this help you at all:
http://www.silverwareconsulting.com/index.cfm/2010/6/21/Send-Push-Notifications-to-an-iPhone-from-ColdFusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CF 6+ provides access to Java objects through [CreateObject()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6979.html).  This would likely be much simpler than rewriting the PHP code.  You could either use the Java objects you linked to, or the ones (with instructions) that @Sam Farmer linked to.

Comment: so maybe I should just use the Java implementation? any advantage of having a pure CF implementation?

Comment: The only advantages I can think of are 1) more readable to pure CF programmers and 2) more expandable/editable to pure CF programmers.  If the libraries work appropriately, I'd just stick with the Java implementation, and update to the newest version when needed.

Comment: http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2010/9/13/Guest-Post-Apple-Push-Notifications-From-ColdFusion-in-Ten-Minutes-or-Less

Comment: Updated ColdFusion URL is: http://www.raymondcamden.com/2010/09/13/Guest-Post-Apple-Push-Notifications-From-ColdFusion-in-Ten-Minutes-or-Less/

Answer (score 1):

I've created a wrapper for both APNS and GCM: https://github.com/RickGroenewegen/pusher